# Where to put complex function in ember-cli application?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm getting oriented to the structure of an ember.js application, and I think I understand the purpose of the routes, controllers, models, templates and helpers.

The thing that I don't understand is where I would put a complex function. Suppose I have an action called `computeSuggestions`, that lives in a controller. It may happen that this one action is very big and complicated, and would be easier to test if it were in its own module, where it could be defined as a pure function.

What would be the typical way to handle this? I'm not very experienced with JavaScript import statements, but I know enough to know that they aren't as easy as in Java or Python. I'm also unsure where in the directory structure would be the normal place for such a function.

Comment: I'm even confused about where to put a simple `.on('click', ` function...

Comment: Ember is challenging to learn, I'm still a novice, but the community is very helpful, just ask a question on SO or http://discuss.emberjs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the docs at http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-modules, it seems like the best place for something like this would be in the /app/utils folder.

Comment: This seems the right ember-cli approach. And I see that `ember g util my-function` creates the module for me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using Ember Mixins for this functionality, you can read more about them here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html

Example:

`app/mixins/compute-suggestions-controller.js`:

```
export default Ember.Mixin.create({
    actions: {
        computeSuggestions: function(modelOrSomething) {
            // Do your complicated action here
        }
    }
});
```

`app/controllers/your-controller.js`:

```
import ComputeSuggestionsControllerMixin from '../mixins/compute-suggestions-controller';

export default Ember.Controller.extend(ComputeSuggestionsControllerMixin, {
    // Rest of controller definition here
});
```

The action `computeSuggestions` would then be available as an action on your controller, as the controller was extended with the mixin.

If you're looking for a more generic solution than just using mixins, then you're free to use the ES6 module pattern to import any module or service that you need.  I usually put my generic stuff into `app/utils/module-name.js`, and simply import where needed via `import utilName from '../utils/util-name.js';`.

Hope that helps!